# open link in svg with target _self

Tags: svg, xlink

I have an svg with links e.g.

```
<a xlink:href="http://example.com" target="_self"></a>
```

Any  idea why the link opens as an iframe instead of acting like a normal _self target? opening the link in the same window I am at?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer

Using _parent does the trick like so

```
<a xlink:href="http://example.com" target="_parent"></a>
```